# Usando telas em Tkinter-Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Tudo bem com vcs?
Então, estou fazendo um programa teste de telas, a função dele seria apenas um teste que consiste em: Abrir uma tela(chamada por um botão) e fechar a que estava aberta. Não sei como fazer isso, já tentei usar laços de repetição, mas sem êxito...
Código:
from tkinter import *

```
def bt_click():

    janela2 = Tk()
    teste2 = janela2
    janela2.title("Teste2")
    janela2.geometry("200x200+300+300")


janela = Tk()

bt1 = Button(janela, text = "Click me", command = bt_click)

bt1.place(x = 50, y = 100)

janela["bg"] = "green"
janela.geometry("300x300+300+300")
janela.mainloop()
```

minha ideia era:
Colocar toda a janela em um laço while, e fazer assim:

```
teste = 1
while teste == 1:
   janela() ...
```

e quando chamasse a outra janela(janela 2), no final da função, fazer com que a variável teste virasse 2 ou qualquer outro número, mas acho que como a variável teste fica dentro da função da janela2, ela se torna local..
Como proceder? Abraços

Comment: Desculpem a bagunça do código, quando passei para esse editor de texto, ele ficou bagunçado :(

Comment: Quado colar código aqui, voce dece selecionar ele e clicar no botão de formatação `{}` lá em cima.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que ter uma referência fora da função que cria a nova janela para a janela criada -  aí é só chamar o método `.destroy` dela.
E isso não precisa ser uma variável global - você pode ter uma lista que contenha todas as janelas criadas - sem ter uma variável com um nome fixo pra cada uma.

```
import tkinter

raiz = None
janelas = []

def criar():
    janela = tkinter.Toplevel(raiz)
    janela.title("janela  {}".format(len(janelas)))
    janelas.append(janela)

def destruir():
    janelas.pop(0).destroy()

def principal():
    global raiz
    raiz = tkinter.Tk()
    bt_criar = tkinter.Button(raiz, text="criar", command=criar)
    bt_destruir = tkinter.Button(raiz, text="destruir", command=destruir)
    bt_criar.pack(side="left")
    bt_destruir.pack(side="right")

principal()
tkinter.mainloop()
```